# Calculating camera pose from fundamental matrix, with known translation vector?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

If I have calculated my fundamental matrix from stereo correspondence

x'Fx = 0

in which x' and x has been estimated by the use of block matching, could I then (if I know my intrinsics and translation vector for the stereo pair) calculate their relative pose (i.e rotation)?
Since

E = K^T F K and E = [R T]

R being essentially three unknown rotations. I find this a potentially elegant solution to my stereo calibration problem for which I know my intrinsics and translation vector very accurately. Or is there something I am missing or has misunderstood about what the matrices represent?